# CakePHP -Call to a member function allow() on null

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

When I enter the user registration information and click the Register button then I have an error on this line in this function.

```
$this->Auth->allow(['register', 'login', 'logout', 'verification']);
```

Userscontroller.php

```
class UsersController extends AppController
{
    public function beforeFilter(EventInterface $event)
    {
        parent::beforeFilter($event);
        // Allow users to register and logout.
        // You should not add the "login" action to allow list. Doing so would
        // cause problems with normal functioning of AuthComponent.
        $this->Auth->allow(['register', 'login', 'logout', 'verification']);
        $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout('products');
    }
// ...
}
```

Comment: So, `$this->Auth` is obviously null then. Go figure out why, we can not possibly do that for you based on that snippet you have shown.

Comment: what error? any output has been produced by this script?

Comment: It's resolved now

Comment: I had to add the routes.